# Stream very big MP4 base64 through the src tag in an HTML video element

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, mp4

Somehow we have the video in the base64 format, and want to stream it in a video element in the HTML like this:

```
<video controls> 
  <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAHGZ0eXBtcDQyAAAAAG1wNDJpc29....../l/L+X8v5AAAAMgfDg=="> 
</video>
```

But the videos we have are big, around 300mb mp4 per file.

We tried to load the entire video data in the src, but the base64 data was too big to be loaded in the (browser) memory.

So, we need a way to stream the base64 video from the file, and not to load it in the memory.


**So how can we divide the base64 of the mp4 file into small chunks, and just load these into memory.**

So for example if we have this:

```
 <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAAAHGZ0eXBtcDQyAAL+X8v5AAAAMgfDg==">
```

We need it to be cut into 3 other data like this:

```
<source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,FIRST+BASE64+CHUNK=="> 
<source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,SECOND+BASE64+CHUNK=="> 
<source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,THIRD+BASE64+CHUNK==">
```

Comment: Simple answer is, you can't do that. you'll need to stream from the server

Comment: @JaromandaX OK. How can I do that on a local node server?

Comment: by searching for `stream video from node server` - implement the streaming using the methods found in your search, and if you have problems with that, ask another question

Comment: @JaromandaX I already have searched for that; but thought you would have a better answer, cause all the answers lead to pipe the stream into another file, and I am already on local host, so why do I need to copy the file to stream from it. 
The file I have would be encoded, so I will need to process it first, generating the video in base64.
So how can I stream from the base64 directly?

Comment: `how can I stream from the base64` - by converting it to binary first (you don't have to save the binary version, just pipe it), because you can't stream base64 (easily)